# Reactjs sweetalert2 put input above html

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert2

I have a sweetalert popup that prompts the user to change their password.  I have the main input field asking the user for their current password, then I have some html with input boxes asking the user to enter their new password twice.  I'd like to have the input field above the html, however I can't figure out how to do it.  Here is my code:

```
const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal)
    MySwal.fire({
      title: 'Change Password?',
      focusConfirm: true,
      input: 'password',
      inputPlaceholder: 'Enter your current password...',
        html:
          '<input id="newPassword1" type="password" placeholder="Enter your new password..." /><br />' +
          '<input id="newPassword2" type="password" placeholder="Confirm your new password..." />' ,
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonColor: 'grey',
        confirmButtonText: 'Update!',
        allowOutsideClick: true,
        inputValidator: (value) => {
          if (!value) {
            return 'You need to write something!'
          }
        }
    })
```

[image]

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: What does that mean? "above the HTML"??? I don't understand what you're trying to say at all.

Comment: Sweetalert only allows you one input field, if you want more you have to add an html string manually.  In the code snippet above there's an "html" field which is where I put the other two input boxes.  The default is that the sweetalert input renders below the html.  I'd like to set it up so the input goes above. Let me know if you have any thoughts.  Thanks!

Comment: So you want the field that says "Enter your current password" to be on top of the 3 input fields?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Sounds good - I have posted an answer for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

***EDIT:*** I have updated my answer to also show how to handle 'light' validation...

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5rxrb5?embed=1&file=index.js)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content'

const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);

let changePwSwal = {
  title: 'Change Password?',
  focusConfirm: false,
  html: `
    <input class="swal2-input" id="currentPassword" type="password" placeholder="Enter your current password..." /><br />
    <input class="swal2-input" id="newPassword1" type="password" placeholder="Enter your new password..." /><br />
    <input class="swal2-input" id="newPassword2" type="password" placeholder="Confirm your new password..." />
  `,
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  cancelButtonColor: 'grey',
  confirmButtonText: 'Update!',
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  preConfirm: () => ({
    currentPassword: document.getElementById('currentPassword').value,
    newPassword1: document.getElementById('newPassword1').value,
    newPassword2: document.getElementById('newPassword2').value
  })
};

export default function App() {
  const [formdata, setformdata] = useState();

  const handleResetPassword = () => {
    const resetPw = async () => {
      const swalval = await MySwal.fire(changePwSwal);
      let v = swalval && swalval.value || swalval.dismiss;
      if (v && v.currentPassword && v.newPassword1 && v.newPassword2 || v === 'cancel') {
        if (v.newPassword1 !== v.newPassword2) {
          await MySwal.fire({ type: 'error', title: 'Passwords do not match!' });
          resetPw();
        } else if (v !== 'cancel') {
          setformdata(swalval);
        }
      } else {
        await MySwal.fire({ type: 'error', title: 'All fields are required!!' });
        resetPw();
      }
    }

    resetPw();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleResetPassword}>Reset Password</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(formdata, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: No problem! I also added some more validation :) Should be good to go from here.